# "Subterranean", but for planets/surfaces other than Earth

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

> Subterranean : existing, situated, or operating below the surface of the earth; underground.

Informally, we can use *subterranean* to describe that which lies below the surface; technically, *terranean* refers to *terra*, the Latin name for Earth.

What word could we use to mean that which lies below a surface, in general. I.e., what would we say about caves under the surface of Mars, "submartian"?

Comment: Well, there's "earth" the substance, and "Earth" the planet.  One could make the case that there's lowercase-e-earth on Mars, for instance.

Comment: For what it's worth, sci-fi writers have from time to time used "sublunar" to mean "underground on the moon". E.g., from Jack Williamson's story "The Equalizer" in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, March 1947, p. 18](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v39n01_1947-03_AK#page/n17/mode/2up): For the actual fort was far beneath the crater. A vast web of tunnels sheltered hangars, shops, barracks, and magazines. The launching tubes, trained forever on the Earth, were hidden in deep pits. Somewhere in that sublunar labyrinth, we could hope to find our riddle answered.

Comment: Possibly some form of the word _lithos_ might serve (see also “lithobreaking” = crashing into the planet’s surface), but the answers below indicate “subterranean” is the accepted usage.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Don't you mean "lithobraking"?

Comment: @Bof, yes, of course. But it’s a typo that kinda works.

Comment: "Sublunar" also has another, different meaning, though.

Comment: Why not just use "subterrainian"? Like *terranean*, but for generic *terrain*.

Comment: « technically, _terranean_ refers to _terra_, the Latin name for Earth » — No. _Terra_ is the word used in Latin to refer to the earth as a celestial body, that is true; but it is first and foremost the common noun used to refer to earth, dirt, soil, the surface of the planet, that thing we walk on and that you can dig into.

Comment: FWIW, “submartian” would actually be “subarean” or something like that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you sure about Terra being the Latin word for he earth as a celestial body? I have read (in on old sci-fi magazine) that the proper Latin word is Tellus, and in fact the words [Tellus](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/122) and [Tellurian](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/121) have been used by sci-fi writers such as E. E. Smith and C. S. Lewis.

Comment: @bof In _Latin_, not sci-fi. The actual Romans did use the word _Terra_ to refer to the earth as a celestial body. They also used _Tellus_ for that, but whereas _terra_ is originally a common noun meaning just ‘earth, dirt’ which was personified as a deity that represented the planet, _Tellus_ is originally the name of a deity that was then de-personified to refer to the planet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, very interesting. Tellus and Terra are so similar, I guess they have a common ancestor?

Comment: @bof Nope, no historical relationship at all. _Terra_ is from the Proto-Indo-European root _*ters-_ meaning ‘to dry’ (Latin _terra_ < Italic _terzā_ < PIE _*térs-eh₂-_). From the same root you get words like _thirst_ < Proto-Germanic _*þurstuz_ < PIE _*tr̥s-tú-_. _Tellūs_, on the other hand is from the root _*telh₂-_ ‘carry, hold up’, which you also find in _tolerate_, _-late/-lation_, _atlas_ (since Atlas carries the world on his shoulders), etc. So _tellūs_ is the ground that carries us, while _terra_ is the dry land (as opposed to sea or wetlands).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This question is predicated on the wrong definition of "Terra". As seen at [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/terra#Latin):

> 1. ground, dry land
> 2. **earth, soil, dirt**

That is, not "Earth" (the planet) but instead "earth", meaning "dirt" or "ground".

So, ***[subterranean](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/subterranean)*** is acceptable to describe anything underground, whether under the surface of Planet Earth or not.

**Edit:** I would not suggest using *"subsurface"* unless it was acceptable to include *underwater* things such as a *submarine*.

Comment: Wiktionary is a questionable resource.

Comment: @Mitch You will need to prove that the actual definition there is questionable.

Comment: I agree with @Spencer and feel this is backed up by [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=terra): *terra* - literally "dry land" (as opposed to "sea"); from PIE root *ters-* "to dry" (source also of Sanskrit *tarsayati* "dries up," Avestan *tarshu-* "dry, solid," Greek *teresesthai* "to become or be dry," Latin *torrere* "dry up, parch".  So *terra* could refer to the dry surface of any planet or satellite.  With all that said, I also feel **subsurface** would do just as well.

Comment: I imagine when you have earth in a circuit on Mars you'd probably still call it earth.

Comment: Maybe _subtellurian_ (under planet Earth (Tellus)) should refer to the planets that are [inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferior_and_superior_planets) to Earth, i.e. Venus and Mercury. In what other way could you be "underneath" an entire planet?

Comment: @Mitch The Wiktionary entry includes quite a few references to back up the definition. Lack of such references is what can make a Wiktionary entry questionable.

Comment: @chepner 1) I couldn't find _any_ external links there and minimal internal links to synonyms 2) my comment (which seems to be much more unpopular than popular) was intended to point out that in general Wiktionary is not a reputable resource (as opposed to OED, MW, or frankly most any other published dictionary). We could have a long discussion, not appropriate for a comment thread here, about the reliability of Wiktionary. Also a separate one about the meaning and definition of words, technical vs informal defintions and derivations.

Answer (score 33):

NASA uses ***subterranean***, as in this [press release](https://www.nasa.gov/press/2015/march/nasa-s-hubble-observations-suggest-underground-ocean-on-jupiters-largest-moon):

> NASA’s Hubble Space Telescope has the best evidence yet for an
>   underground saltwater ocean on Ganymede, Jupiter’s largest moon. The
>   subterranean ocean is thought to have more water than all the water on
>   Earth's surface.

Granted, the OP asked for an alternate to subterranean, and NASA is perhaps not a leading expert in English, but subterranean seems preferable to a plethora of words specific to every planet and moon on which underground water might be found.  This is especially so now that exoplanets are being found in great number, and the technology to find out if water exists on or inside them is sure to be developed, if it has not already been.

Comment: It's surprisingly bothersome to me that NASA used that term. Not that I *want* them to use "subganymedean," but why not "underground" or "sub-surface?" Sigh.

Comment: @Katherine Lockwood  Their budget doesn't allow for a linguist until they discover aliens. :)  They probably used subterranean in the second sentence because they used underground in the first sentence.

Comment: Planetary scientists refer to the *terrains* of alien worlds pretty regularly.  "Subterranean" always sounded like a word to describe stuff that sits below the terrain, to me.  I think that the trick is to remember that when people spoke of "terra" several thousand years ago they weren't necessarily referring to Terra, the planet that you hear about in science-fiction stories.  "Surface" is actually an incredibly vague term when you start talking about things in the sky too, to be totally honest.

Comment: The latin word terra classically means earth (little e) as in earth, ground, land, country, or an area.  Not big "e" Earth.   Sub terra (subterranean) is simply under ground, or under the earth.

Comment: I think that Latin refers to uppercase Earth as "orbs terrarum", which further supports the claim that terra does not refer to the planet, but rather means "earth" or "land". I think it's appropriate then to use the word "subterranean" to describe places on other planets.

Comment: @ktm5124: Agreed: in classical Latin, you would not primarily call this world *terra*, but rather *orbis terrarum* ("the circle of lands"). Yes, also that obtains for times when the Ancients knew that the world was a ball and not a disc. The word *terra* is most frequently used to mean "land, soil". I see no problem whatsoever with using the word *subterranean* on other planets.

Answer (score 30):

You may use ***[underground](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underground):***

> - occurring, situated, or used below ground level: *an underground tunnel; an underground explosion.*

Collins Dictionary

From: [www.space.com](http://www.space.com/17048-water-on-mars.html):

> - A new study suggests that water also flows on the surface. ... local, or only underground on Mars.

From: www.sky.com:

> - [Evidence Of Life On Mars May Be Underground](http://news.sky.com/story/evidence-of-life-on-mars-may-be-underground-10457299).

Comment: Yes, *ground* (whose Germanic etymology seems related to "foundation") would seem universally applicable - whilst *earth* - meaning "soil", of course wouldn't. One could hardly speak of "Martian earth"!

Comment: ...although the OED gives *The ground considered as a solid stratum.*

Comment: @WS2: Hmm, that begs the question .... what is the Martian equivalent of "earth"? "Mars"? "I let the pebbles of mars trickle through my gloved fingers" hmm nah

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I wouldn't use "pebbles of [lowercase-e] earth", either. In my mind pebbles are lumps of stone, not of earth (though earth may contain pebbles...). For uppercase E I'd only not use it because I've yet to need the distinction. As for the sense of what was meant, "the lumps of [Martian] soil" works fine in my view.

Comment: @Darael: You know what I mean. Yes, of course, we can avoid the issue entirely by using a separate category of term. That's not in the spirit of what I was asking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to the extent that I do, that's what I tried to cover in the last sentence. If that doesn't address it then I honestly *don't* know what you mean, though I probably *should*.

Answer (score 15):

**Subterranean** or **Underground** are perfectly acceptable usage for other planets or moons composed of rocky material.

As indicated by others, **terra** frequently refers to **earth** as in soil or land, rather than **Earth** the planet.

**Earth is not the only planet that shares its name with a substance** (Mercury does, too, but in that case it is a coincidence whereas in the case of Earth it is not.)

There are many words and phrases based on the root **terra-**. These include **terracotta**, **terra firma**, **terrace** and most tellingly, **terrain**. If we cannot use the word "subterranean" to refer to underground features on Mars, then by the same logic we cannot speak of **Martian terrain** and the position becomes absurd.

In fact the four inner planets of the solar system are said to be **[terrestrial planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_planet)**, meaning they are composed of earth and rock.

The situation is different for gas giants, such as jupiter, or bodies composed largely of water / ice such as Europa or Titan, which have an ice crust. The latter are believed to have a **subsurface** ocean rather than a subterranean one. (They also are believed to have features analogous to volcanoes where molten ice rather than molten rock is spewed out. These are known as cryovolcanoes.)

Answer (score 14):

This distinction doesn't seem useful to me. Furthermore, as Spencer points out, it is based on false premise: the question implicitly assumes that *[terra](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dterra)* is **only** "the Latin name for Earth". In fact, it is also the Latin word for *earth.* Dirt, ground, or dry land. Mars may not be "Earth", uppercase-E, but it certainly has "earth", lowercase-e.

I don't think it even makes sense to interpret the *terra* in *subterranean* as meaning "Earth". Are subterranean structures "beneath Earth" (the planet as a whole)? No, they aren't. The Earth's center of gravity is a point inside the planet, so nothing can be beneath it. Subterranean structures are beneath earth.

The same confusion in French has led to the coinage of some silly words like *amarsir* "land on Mars" (by analogy with *atterrir* "land" on dry land)" and *amarsissage,* but these words are not necessary and are not favored by official organizations, as explained in the following Le Monde blog post "[DICO – Doit-on dire « amarsissage » ou « atterrissage sur Mars » ?](http://bigbrowser.blog.lemonde.fr/2012/08/06/dico-doit-on-dire-amarsissage-ou-atterrissage/)":

> Les experts soulignent que l’apparition de ces néologismes est dû à
>   une confusion : la racine d' »atterrissage » ne désigne par la Terre,
>   la planète, mais bien la terre, l’élément. Il n’y aurait donc pas de
>   sens à parler d’un « amarsissage » puisque, même sur Mars, le robot
>   s’est posé sur de la terre.

(My translation: "Experts highlight that the appearance of these neologisms is due to a confusion: the root of "atterrissage" doesn't designate Earth, the planet, but earth, the element. There is therefore no sense in speaking of "amarsissage" because, even on Mars, the robot rests on the earth.")

If you restricted all terms with roots like this to their original, terrestrial references, you'd also be unable to speak of "oceans" on any planet but Earth since the word "ocean" comes from the same root as the Greek personification of the ocean "[Oceanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanus)". Oops! Tell that to the people writing about a hypothesized ["ocean" of Jupiter's moon Europa](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=europa%20ocean&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). (Or should that be "a sub-surface body of water on Jupiter's satellite Europa"?)

In fact, I found that the actual word "[terra](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=T5130100)" itself (or the plural "terrae") seems to be used in astronomy to refer to particular regions of the moon that are rocky or rough.

Answer (score 13):

A generic term would be '[subsurface](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsurface)' (MW adjective)

> of, relating to, or being something located beneath a surface and especially underground

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a slight turn of thought (and just a touch of fun) is required. We could drop the Latin for some of the planets and look at Greece for the original names of the Roman gods chosen to represent them. On the other hand, just one of them uses a Latin derivative, as with "Jovan moons," "Jovan asteroids," and "Jovan LaGrange points" (by Zeus ... I mean, Jove). From the late 14th century, Jove had become a poetic term for the planet Jupiter, stemming from the Latin Iovis.

From the inner orbit outward:

Mercury might take sub-mercurian/sub-mercurial or sub-hermitian (very doubtful on the last one – a bit rough on the artistic flow).

Venus might prove difficult using the Greek Aphrodite, and sci-fi writers have already leaped upon the term Venusian (capitalized). It sounds pretty solid.

I'm sure a truly 'solar' language will have to glimpse some of the original Greek. I found that NASA did just that when I visited some of their many informative pages regarding the planet Mars. There, they used the term areocentric to describe a Mars orbit. Roman Mars equals Greek Ares, ergo areocentric. The word seemed to flow for me with a pleasant grace. In this venue, could underground on Mars become sub-arean? The term terrain might even reach as far as, dare I say it ... areain...?

For Jupiter, it seems to be stuck with Jove, a Latin derivative, so below the surface clouds of Jupiter might be found sub-Jovan (capitalized again).

Saturn will likely stick with Saturnine (so many capitalizations) cloud cover and, therefore, sub-saturnine (NOT capitalized - yay!).

The sniggering joke of the planets, Uranus, is already linked to Uranian.

Apparently, Neptune may go either way, with the accepted adjectives Neptunian and Poseidean.

Pluto, our newest non-planet (aka dwarf-planet) already uses the adjective Plutonian. Considering the Grecian Underworld to be the home for both Heaven and Hell in Greek mythology, might sub-Seventh Heaven also apply? Sub-Cloud 9? Naw. Just sub-Plutonian (capitalization required).

Answer (score 0):

You can use creative liberty with the prefix sub. Subglacial, Subterranian, Subatmospheric, Subsurface, sub-lithospheric and underground, subaquatic, sub-benthic, sub-volcanic, sub-magmatic, speleogenesis ... If a new kind of planetary surface exists which requires a new description, you can use sub/under to describe it. Before describing the subsurface of new types of surface, the surface must be defined: Sea is used to describe a lot of things which are not water, and ice is used to describe CO2 ice, so terrain for the moment is a very suitable term for land surface.

When i need info like this i check out "mining/cave glossary" on google.